# Using discord.py, how would i check how much messages a user has sent in a specific channel

Tags: python, discord.py

Using discord.py, how would i check how much messages a user has sent in a specific channel, and then for example every week, the bot will send a message for how much messages a user has sent
for example, if i sent 30 messages in "#test" in a week, when the week ends it will send "@User has sent: 30 messages in #test".

I'm not sure what to try.

All I have setup is my bot with:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
```

> no errors

Answer (score 0):

Look at the discord.py [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history).

You can use:

```py
counter = 0
async for message in channel.history():
    if message.author == client.user:
        counter += 1
```

or something similar. More details are in the documentation.